# jCarousel, fetching data Just-In-Time

Tags: jcarousel

I want to use jCarousel and I want to be able to fetch the next batch of images Just-In-Time with an Ajax call, if they have not already been downloaded

The Ajax examples on the jCarousel site seem to show the entire set of items being loaded using Ajax. I want to just load the next set if they are not yet present.

It looks like I need to use this method, `itemLoadCallback`. Anyone able to confirm this?

TIA

Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax_php.html)  might help.